# bool x = (A || B && C)

Tags: c++, if-statement, operator-precedence

Is this expression equivalent to `((A || B) && C)` or to `(A || (B && C))`?

For example:

Let A=1, B=0, C=0. What is the outcome of this expression? Is it 0 (case 1) or 1 (case 2)?

Comment: Why don't you test it out? We're not here to compile an expression and test it for you.

Comment: As @gexicide said, this is called operator precedence. In this case, you're asking about which has a higher precendence, a `"logical AND" (&&)` or a `"logical OR" (||)`. Once you know those terms, a quick google leads you to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) or [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bxt6kc4.aspx) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) or [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/). All of these tell you that logical ANDs should be evaluated before logical ORs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `&&` operator has higher precedence than the `||` in C++ (and most similar languages), so your second alternative is correct, i.e.:

```
(A || B && C) == (A || (B && C))
```

You can check out the precedence of all operators in C++ here:
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence